# Yum broken while updating libcurl

Tags: centos, yum

On my Centos 6 server I updated curl using city-fan.repo but after installing I have issue with yum... I found ( after searching hours) that it was due to libssh2 older version so I removed it and downloaded again to recompile it, But to compile it GCC is not installed, When I try to ./configure  libssh2-1.6.1-20150617 I have this error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

, So I downloaded these packages from Centos repo as I am unable to use yum to install gcc:

```
cloog-ppl-0.15.7-1.2.el6.x86_64.rpm                               glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64.rpm   kernel-headers-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.rpm
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64.rpm  gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64.rpm      glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64.rpm    mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
cpp-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64.rpm                  glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64.rpm  glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64.rpm  ppl-0.10.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

When I try to install those I get this:

```
 rpm -ivh *.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 (which is newer than glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64) is already installed
        package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 (which is newer than glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64) is already installed
        file /usr/sbin/build-locale-archive from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/sbin/tzdata-update from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /lib64/ld-2.12.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /lib64/libc-2.12.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /sbin/ldconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /sbin/sln from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM1364.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM1371.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM1388.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM1390.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM1399.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM933.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM935.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM937.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/gconv/IBM939.so from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/sbin/glibc_post_upgrade.x86_64 from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/sbin/iconvconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
        file /usr/sbin/iconvconfig.x86_64 from install of glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
```

and if I run any yum command it is displaying me this error:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I am very novice to this...Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have majorly hosed your system.

You downloaded rpm packages that are older than the ones you already have installed (that's what that error message is telling you).

Get the rpm packages for the libssh2 and curl packages you removed and fix yum.

Then find a better way to do whatever you were trying to do in the first place. Anything that requires you to upgrade a core component of the operating system (like libcurl) in a way that the official packages can't handle is broken by design.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing the following:

```
yum provides libssh2.so.1
```

then installing one of the providing packages

e.g. `yum install libssh2` ?